# How to create .exe executable file for php zend framework project

Tags: zend-framework

I developed a project in php using zend framework and mysql. 
Now i need to convert the project into executable file.

Is it possible to create a .exe file from zend framework project?

Comment: .exe is for Desktop applications. PHP + Zend framework is a web application

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this - https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/